# Why does this XQuery fail when I add a numerical condition with xs:long?

Tags: java, xquery

I'm currently trying to learn XQuery and have got stuck. I'm using MXQuery as the engine ( http://mxquery.org/ ) and 
am trying to execute the following query string using the Java API to MXQuery :

```
    declare variable $pfn external;                          
    declare variable $cap external;                          
    declare variable $rate as xs:long external;              
    for $p in doc('CapabilitiesDefn.xml')//Site/Function  
    for $c in $p/Capability                                  
    let $r1 := $c/Rate/min                                   
    let $r2 := $c/Rate/max                                   
     where $p/@name=$pfn                                     
       and $c/@name=$cap                                     
       and $rate > xs:long($r1)
    return xs:string($p/@name)
```

In the java code I get the exception

```
javax.xml.xquery.XQQueryException: ch.ethz.mxquery.exceptions.TypeException: Sequence Type Matching Failed: Incorrect type: Expected xs:long, encountered  type :xs:integer
```

If I remove the line 'and $rate > xs:long($r1) ' from the query, the query succeeds and returns the expected result.

If I change xs:long to xs:integer in the query, the query succeeds and returns the expected result.

Trouble is I need $rate to be a long.

Here is the XML I am querying

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CapabilityDefinition>
    <Site name="TOC2">
        <Function name="fred" ID="123456">
            <Capability name="st">
                <Rate>
                    <min>1000000</min>
                    <max>3000000</max>
                </Rate>
            </Capability>
            <Capability name="supervise">
                <Rate>
                    <min>1000000</min>
                    <max>3000000</max>
                </Rate>
            </Capability>
        </Function>
    </Site>
    <Site name="CES11">
        <Function name="bob" ID="231100000001102104">
            <Capability name="df">
                <Rate>
                    <min>1000000</min>
                    <max>3000000000</max>
                </Rate>
            </Capability>
        </Function>
    </Site>
</CapabilityDefinition>
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value that you are setting for `$rate` is being evaluated as an integer. Are you sure that what is being set is a long?

You need to ensure that the value being set for the external variable `$stat` is indeed `xs:long`. You can verify the behavior by hard-coding a value. Changing your XQuery to use the below assignment works without error:

```
declare variable $rate as xs:long := xs:long(9000000);
```

However, this will fail with the same error message:

```
declare variable $rate as xs:long := 9000000;
```

Another option would be to accept the external value without an explicit type, and construct `xs:long` from the value in your FLWOR:

```
declare variable $pfn external;                          
declare variable $cap external;                          
declare variable $rate external;              
for $p in doc('CapabilitiesDefn.xml')//Site/Function  
for $c in $p/Capability                                  
let $r1 := $c/Rate/min                                   
let $r2 := $c/Rate/max                                   
 where $p/@name=$pfn                                     
   and $c/@name=$cap                                     
   and xs:long($rate) > xs:long($r1)
return xs:string($p/@name)
```

Comment: None of this should be necessary, except to circumvent a bug (or non-conformance) in the XSLT processor.

Comment: @MichaelKay Saxon complains when declared as `declare variable $rate as xs:long := 9000000;` Seems that it evaluates as `xs:integer` but only throws the error if the variable is referenced in the FLWOR. Severity: error
Description: XPTY0004: Required item type of value of variable $rate is xs:long; supplied value has item type xs:integer
Start location: 11:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#ERRXPTY0004

Comment: Sorry, I was focussing on the way the variable is used, not the way it is bound. With an external variable the rules are a little implementation-defined; Saxon will apply the function conversion rules which mean that supplying an untypedAtomic "900000" will work, but supplying an xs:integer "900000" won't. It's a bad design mistake in my view that the function conversion rules don't do automatic down-casting to the required type; it's also a design mistake in XQuery (unlike XSLT) that the function conversion rules don't apply to variable bindings.

Comment: Thanks a mil for the answer!!! It works. Seems like there is a bug in MXQuery or I don't understand it correctly.